# How can I trigger a build from a specific folder only in a monorepo? (buildkite)

Tags: buildkite

We have a monorepo with 3 systems inside it.  I want to create a separate build for each of the systems.

How can I trigger a pipeline only when files change in a specific folder?

We are using github

```yaml
steps:

  - label: 'Lint'
    command: '.buildkite/scripts/lint.sh'
    agents:
      node: true
      queue: xyz

  - label: 'Run Tests'
    command: '.buildkite/scripts/tests.sh'
    agents:
      node: true
      queue: xyz
```

Comment: post your service file

Comment: The build pipeline yaml?  I'm not sure what you mean by sevice file

Comment: yes, pipeline yaml

Comment: I've edited the main post to include the yaml

Answer (score 3):

buildkite support emailed me this solution:

> Thanks for reaching out! It sounds like you may want to take a look at using the monorepo diff plugin!
>
> https://github.com/chronotc/monorepo-diff-buildkite-plugin
>
> There is a good medium article here as well on setting it up: https://medium.com/geekculture/set-up-continuous-integration-for-monorepo-using-buildkite-61539bb0ed76
>
> Let us know if you have any other questions or need more assistance!
>
> Cheers,